# Overlay Gradient to an Image in Android

Tags: android

In my app, I retrieve images from database and add texts. Users can click a button to share them to other apps. I need to add a gradient background in order to make the texts more visible. Currently I'm using:

```
Bitmap gradient = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.gradient_high), bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), false);
canvas.drawBitmap(gradient, 0, 0, paint);
```

The gradient image is a png file under `drawable`. The problem is that many narrow bars become visible once the gradient is drawn to the original image, as if the resolution is very low. But actually they are of the same resolution.

However, when I display the images in my app, I'm adding the gradient directly from XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#65000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Basically I just specify it as the background of a `RelativeLayout` and put it under my `ImageView`, which holds the original image. It gives me a very smooth combined image.

I don't think I can do the same if I want to share the image, since I'm programmatically adding stuff to the original image in Java and share it, not just displaying it in my app. I want to find a way to achieve the same image quality though. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what the "narrow bars" are? Also as this is kind of a visual question, could you add more details around what you want?

Comment: @JoxTraex It's the horizontal strips on the image, looks like the image in your TV when the TV signal is bad. I just want to add a gradient background to the image I get from database, without sacrificing the quality. Or maybe I should convert the XML into a bitmap in my case?